# Prove that a given function is Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

I need to prove that the function $f(t,x):(a,b)\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ 
$$ f(t,x)=(t^2-x) \frac{\log(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}$$

is locally lipschitz with respect to $x$.

I think that is globally Lipschitz, but I'm not sure if this is true because I'm not convinced with my proof. 
Of course, the key is that $\log(y)/y \leq 1$ when $y>1$. But I have

$$\|f(t,x)-f(t,y) \|=\left\| (t^2-x) \frac{\log(1+x^2)}{1+x^2} - (t^2-y) \frac{\log(1+y^2)}{1+y^2} \right\|  $$

and I'm not sure if I can simplify this by removing the fraction. I 've tried

$$ \left\| (t^2-x) \frac{\log(1+x^2)}{1+x^2} - (t^2-y) \frac{\log(1+y^2)}{1+y^2} \right\|\leq \left\| (t^2-x)- (t^2-y) \frac{\log(1+y^2)}{1+y^2} \right\|= \left\|  (t^2-y) \frac{\log(1+y^2)}{1+y^2} -(t^2-x)\right\|\leq \left\|  (t^2-y) -(t^2-x)\right\|=\|x-y \|$$

But I think that this is not true if $t^2-x<0$, and It's suspicious that the Lipschitz constant is $L=1$

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: I've seen with wolfram that $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty } \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(t,x) = 0$, so with that can I deduce that is Lipschitz? I think I can, but it's not the proof that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is continuous, hence, by the Mean value theorem, $f$ is locally Lipschitz.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the Mean Value Theorem. 

If $\frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\partial x} $ is continuous (in $I\times  \mathbb{R}$), exists an interval $[a,b]$ and $c\in [a,b]$ such that $ \frac{f(t,x)-f(t,y)}{x-y} =\left. \frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\partial x} \right|_{x=c} $ and then $f(t,x) $ is locally Lipschitz with respect to $x$ with constant $L = \left. \frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\partial x} \right|_{x=c}$
Is this correct?